# R package access denied installation error

Tags: r, rstudio

> Error in install.packages :
> path[1]="\Users\name\Documents\R\win-library\4.1": Access is denied

I am trying to install basic r packages, and keep getting this error even though I have full permissions for this folder. I have tried different packages so it is something going on with my permissions.

Comment: What OS are you using? How did you install R itself. That path doesn't look like a windows path and yet it as "win-library" in the path. That seems odd.

Comment: Please include information about `.libPaths()` and `sessionInfo()` as well as the code you are using to install the packages

Answer (score 2):

Hey I figured it out using [this guide](https://rpubs.com/tomhopper/windows_nonadmin_install) I was confused because I had permissions to the document folder but because it was being backed up to the network I was getting an error. I also had to manually set permissions to the r-library files to make sure they weren't 'read only'

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem in the past. The way I fixed it was to close R, navigate to C:\Users\name\Documents in Windows Explorer, delete a file called '.Rhistory' located in that directory.

I then reopened R and then used the install.packages function as normal, and it ran with no problems.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).